# Prevent commands from populating command-line history

Tags: command-line, command-history

I would like some commands to not be registered in the `cmdline` history. Is there a way to do this? I can't seem to find anything about it in the doc.

The story: I accidentally deleted a file with `:Delete` from `vim-eunuch`. It would be great if it could keep out of the history.

Comment: you can manually edit the vimhistory file (or how is it called), but it could leave other traces like file modification/access etc.

Comment: just close vim, and do it in another editor. It shouldn't be present in the history then

Comment: See `:h histdel()`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Indeed, it looks to be the only way -- I was hoping for a way to prevent the history file population rather than having to manipulate it afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are trying to solve the wrong problem, or you are trying to solve a problem the wrong way. I could be wrong but to me if you need to delete your history to avoid an issue, there is probably something you could do differently.

However, I was curious to see if it is possible to come up with a solution. So I gave it a try and here is what I have:

```
let g:commands_to_delete_from_history = ['echo']

function! DeleteCommandsFromHistory()
    let lastHistoryEntry = histget('cmd', -1)
    let lastCommand = split(lastHistoryEntry, '\s\+')[0]

    if (index(g:commands_to_delete_from_history, lastCommand) >= 0)
        call histdel('cmd', -1)
    endif
endfunction

augroup history_deletion
    autocmd!
    autocmd CmdlineLeave * call DeleteCommandsFromHistory()
augroup END
```

This code should be added to your vimrc (or even better you should put `DeleteCommandsFromHistory()` in a dedicated autoload plugin, but that's not the point of this answer).

You will need to modify the list `g:commands_to_delete_from_history` to include the commands you don't want to have in your history.

Then what the code does is the following:

It create an autocommand on the event `CmdLineLeave` which is triggered each time to were in the command line mode (started with `:`) and you leave it one way or another.

The autocommand calls the function `DeleteCommandsFromHistory()`. This function gets the last entry in the history, split it to keep only the first word (e.g. `echo` if the command was `:echo "foo"`), and if the word is found in the `g:commands_to_delete_from_history` list then it calls `histdel` to delete the last entry from the history.

I tested the code very quickly and it seems to be working but there is probably some edge cases that I forgot but this is a proof of concept that you should tweak as you like.

Related help topics:

- [`:h histget()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#histget%28%29)
- [`:h split()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#split%28%29)
- [`:h index()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#index%28%29)
- [`:h histdel()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#histdel%28%29)
- [`:h CmdlineLeave`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#CmdlineLeave)

Comment: Thank you for such an interesting answer. I wish there was bash `HISTIGNORE` counterpart in Vim. I've given your function a try, it looks to do the job just fine so far -- I'll update if I encounter any edge case.

Comment: To make this robust is enormously complex—commands have abbreviations, so you need to invoke the completion functions to figure out what the last command actually is; also, not all command names stop at the first whitespace (s and g are the two most evident examples). A fine answer, just want to point out that it’s hard ans may not be worth it—particularly if it breaks on some things

Comment: @D.BenKnoble You are completely right, that's why I made it clear in my answer that I did it just for fun and that a lot of edge cases are probably not handled properly

Comment: @statox Agreed 100% ! It was clear to me, just wanted to point out a few for OP

Comment: @statox Found an error! When the command is empty or only spaces, the *lastCommand* variable is undefined. I'd go for `if trim(lastHistoryEntry) == "" | return | endif` before setting *lastCommand*.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thank you for the info. Indeed, if this is making it *robust*, I won't bother. This piece of code has made a good job so far and does not need to do more.

Comment: @Biggybi there is an empty function.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble No way